# Form post request and storing data received

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, post

I have a very simple form making a post request on submit:

```
<form action="/data" method="post">
      <div class="someclass">
         <label for="username">Username: </label>
         <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="placeholder">
     </div>
     <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

The request goes through, server receives it, sends back a response, and I land on a different page displaying the actual response. Instead, I would just like to store the response in a variable. Is there any way to do this with a `<form>` without using the `XMLHttpRequest` object to make the ajax call?

In case it matters (I don't think it should). The server is a node server running on express.js.

Comment: As per my knowledge you can't do it without ajax call

Comment: You could use the new [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), but that's like using Ajax.

Comment: are you able to say the reason you don't wish to use XMLHttpRequest? Generally this would be considered the correct way to post data to the server without the browser loading the action page. If there's a specific problem you've had using AJAX, it may be simpler to resolve that issue than to reinvent the wheel. There are various dodgy solutions - you could create a hidden iFrame and load up `/data` in it, appending the field values as get params, or do something similar with an image tag, but at the end of the day you're just implementing a poor man's XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly - no reason at all. I was curious to learn if there was a way to do it with forms. I consider the forms way a little cleaner and abstract.  I'll just use XMLHttpRequest. Thank you to all for taking the time to think about this