# get url relative to another url in javascript

Tags: javascript, url

i want to get url relative to another url

**for example**

```
"../d.html".relativeTo("/a/b/c.html"); //==> "/a/d.html"

"g.html".relativeTo("/a/b/c.html"); //==> "/a/b/g.html"

"./f/j.html".relativeTo("/a/b/c.html"); //==> "/a/b/f/j.html"

"../../k/w.html".relativeTo("/a/b/c.html"); //==> "/k/w.html"

"http://www.google.com".relativeTo("/a/b/c.html"); //==> "http://www.google.com"
```

i think there is a simple solution for that because browsers does it for relative url links.

i have tried

```
String.prototype.relativeTo=function(input){
    if(/^https?:\/\//i.test(this)) {
        return this.valueOf();
    }
    else {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = input.replace(/\w+\.\w+/, "") + this;
        return a.href;
    }
}
```

but it returns absolute url

is there some simple way to do that?

Comment: *"is there some simple way"* .... define "simple". Show us what you have tried. This isn't a code writing service and you are expected to show your attempts to solve your issue yourself...then people help when code doesn't act as expected

Comment: i want to write code to process on strings and check these test cases but i though it should have simple solution

Comment: But the key there is that you need to write the code....and ask questions here when you have problems with that code. You have numerous conditions to check so no it's not really a simple exercise. What is your use case?

Comment: yes you are right but this is simply done by the browsers , so there should be a way to use that capability i think

Comment: well there possibly is but that depends on what higher level problem you are trying to solve. Based on those string evaluations and expected output shown ...you would need to write your own parser

Comment: @charlietfl - The OP's question was 'is there any simple method to do that?' He was just asking whether there was any existing method perhaps on the `String` object that could take care of this. His question was not 'can you write the method for me?' (even though the answer provided is that).

Comment: @jgozal well if you put it in those terms then it can also be interpreted as a boolean Yes/No question.

Comment: @charlietfl - are those types of questions not allowed in stackoverflow? This is not a rhetorical question. You have definitely been here for longer than I have.

Comment: For example, I recently asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716107/form-post-request-and-storing-data-received. In my opinion, these yes/no questions with a little bit of explanation are very valid and can be useful to the community.

Comment: @jgozal they typically fall into 2 main categories. One being...I tried some stuff that didn't work ... show me how. --OR-- Give me the code , I haven't tried or done any research ... then the minority are legit but show little sign of research effort. It's always  best to try to prompt some sign of effort put in. Poorly phrased questions are also hard to interpret users intent as this one is

Answer (score 2):

Really interesting, anyway I would like to answer

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function (input) {
   return this.substring(0, input.length) === input;
};

String.prototype.relativeTo = function (input) {
   var toTop = /..\//gi;
   var abs = /^https?:\/\//i;
   var inCurrent = './';
   var matches;

   if (abs.test(this)) {
     return this.valueOf();
   }

   function getLastSegmentIndex() {
     return (input.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) - (input.length - 1);
   }

   try {
     matches = this.match(toTop).length;
   } catch (e) {
     matches = 0;
   }

   if (!matches) {
     return input.slice(0, -getLastSegmentIndex()) + this.valueOf();
   } else if (this.startsWith(inCurrent)) {
     return input.slice(0, -getLastSegmentIndex()) +     


     this.replace(inCurrent, '');
   }

   var segments = input.split('/');
   var i = 0;

   for (; i < matches + 1; i++) {
    segments.pop();
   }

   segments.push((this.replace(toTop, '')));
   return segments.join('/');
};
```

Comment: thank you. just change "return this;" to "return this.valueOf();" for absolute url. thank you again.